# OPENPYXL tutorial / help with AVERAGE DICTIONARY

Tags: python, excel

For my thesis I am trying to extract some data from Excel.
I want to create a list with the name as in excel and then append the values to said list so I can work with it.

### EDIT

I realize I was unclear [in my last post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/313290/using-openpyxl-in-python). This is simply because it was hard to find material on openpyxl (I didn't find the documentation that useful)

After some research I accomplished some things:
I will first explain the process

In excel I have many columns with a header=name of stock
and below values for said stock.

1. **Step 1** would be read the columns and differentiate between names
2. **step 2** create a dictionary from those columns with the key being the name of stock
3. **step 3** is to calculate an average with a function that excludes the input stock from the average .so avg(dictionary,stock i) would calculate the average of my dictionary values while excluding stock i

   ```
   WB=load_workbook(filename=)

   ws = WB.active
   Stockslist={}
   i=0
   for col in ws.columns:
       print("we are at column; "+str(i))
       i+=1
   for cell in col:


       if cell.value=="" or cell.value==None:
           print ("empty column")
           break

       if type(cell.value)==unicode:
           print (" we entered name")
           Stock=str(cell.value)

       else:
           Stockslist.setdefault(Stock,[]).append(cell.value)
   ```

This creates a dictionary with the values,now lets calculate the average while excluding a certain stock

```
      def CalcAverage(stockslist,stock):#stockslist is a dict, stock is a key in said dictionary
          stocki=Stockslist.pop(stock)#remove stock we wanna exclude from dictionary

          avgvalues=[]#create a list that will constitute average values
          
          for k,v in Stockslist.iteritems():
              print k
              avgvalues.append(sum(v)/float(len(v)))
         return avgvalues,stocki
```

now my question is suppose I have:

```
        stockslist={"APPLE":[1,2,3],"TESLA":[4,5,6],"GOOGLE":[7,8,9]}
```

I don't want to create a list that has the average value for apple values and so on.
This has been explained many times before on Stack Exchange

I want to get a list that comprises the mean in a pairwise progression kind of way
so AVGVALUE would be avgvalues=[1+4+7/3, avg of 2Nd values of Stockslist and so on..]

So not as in my code above where I calculate the average per stock and then append it.

Answer (score 1):

I realize what I was doing was simply a pairwise addition of a dictionary values.
This has been answered on Stack Exchange before , therefore this question can be closed.

This was simply because I had never heard of the zip function before.

Kind regards, Here is the correct answer:

```
     def CalcAverage(Stockslist,stock):
          stock_values=Stockslist.pop(stock)#remove stock we wanna exclude from dictionary



           avgvalues=[sum(i)/float(len(i)) for i in zip(*Stockslist.itervalues())]

           return avgvalues,stock_values


          stockslist={"APPLE":[1,2,3],"TESLA":[4,5,6],"GOOGLE":[7,8,9]}

          CalcAverage(stockslist,"GOOGLE")
```